# SSH - Not able to ssh from my laptop to raspberry after rebooting the pi

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, windows, image, ethernet-port

Greetings to the community!

I am struggling establishing an ssh connection from laptop (**Windows 10**) to my pi connected to it through an Ethernet cable (**raspberry pi 3 model B+**).

The process I am following is the above one:

1) Flashing an image (more specifically, [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0sp5a1s6r5ee3kw/ESPX-rasp.tar.gz?dl=0)) to my SD card

2) Go to the **/etc/network/interfaces** file of the image and added the following lines of code

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

so that my pi takes a dynamic ip from the dhcp.

3) Add the SD card in my pi, connect my pi through Ethernet cable into my laptop and boot (**Network Sharing is enabled in Windows options**)

4) Get the static IP(192.168.137.85) of my pi assigned to it and **connect to it through SSH using Putty successfully**

So far so good....

**Unfortunately**, if I reboot my pi (unplugged it or whatever - of course after I have previously ended the SSH connection) and I try again to establish an SSH connection with it, it fails.

The **workaround currently is repeat the procedure above**(flash again the image etc.), but this is not a real solution..

Any idea what could possibly be the reason for the failed ssh connection after the pi reboot? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is that pi image? raspbian? which version of raspbian? or is it something else? `/etc/network/interfaces` hasn't been used to configure network settings for some time

Comment: It is a custom rasbian image.

Comment: As long as we don't know what's customized on your Raspbian we cannot help much because `/etc/network/interface` isn't used on an unmodified Raspbian image. Using it will disable default `dhcpcd` networking.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with RaspiOS 2020-05-28?

Comment: I have not tried Raspbian yet.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that stops the connection process is a possible cause.

- No physical Ethernet connection (bad cable, lose connector, switch off, etc.)
- Not connecting to the actual IP of the Pi (static vs DHCP)
- Pi is using an IP address already in use by another system on the same LAN
- Pi is hung, crashed, or failed to boot
- Windows firewall blocking ping (ICMP), ssh protocols (Pi firewalls usually off)

Successful ping from Windows to Pi means the above issues are not the problem.  Additional things:

- Pi sshd service is not enabled and running
- Userid used for ssh login non-existent or locked on the pi

Adding another user interface, monitor/keyboard/mouse or serial cable is the easiest (and typical) way to debug these issues.

Another approach is capture debugging information when on Pi boot.

1. Put the SD card into a Linux computer and mount the second partition (the Pi's ext4 root partition).
2. Add lines to script /etc/rc.local to capture debugging information to a text file /var/log/netdebug.
3. Unmount and remove the SD card.
4. Insert the SD in the Pi and power on.
5. After a reasonable period of time, connect to the Pi.
6. If you can't login, power off, remove the SD card.
7. Again mount the SD card in a Linux computer and look at the saved debug messages in netdebug.

This method is time-consuming, but doesn't require additional hardware (assuming a Linux system exists to write the SD card in the first place).
Following are example dash script lines to add to /etc/rc.local.

```
# Capture networking information
echo "# date" >/var/log/netdebug
date >>/var/log/netdebug
# Show network interfaces, MAC, IP addresses, status.
echo "\n# ip addr show" >>/var/log/netdebug
ip addr show >>/var/log/netdebug
# Show running (listening) TCP network services.
echo "\n# netstat -lptn" >>/var/log/netdebug
netstat -lptn >>/var/log/netdebug
# Show status of sshd service.
echo "\n# systemctl status sshd.service" >>/var/log/netdebug
systemctl status sshd.service >>/var/log/netdebug
# Show that Ethernet is working.
# Replace 192.168.1.1 with known valid IP on Pi's LAN.
echo "\n# ping -c 3 192.168.1.1" >>/var/log/netdebug
ping -c 3 192.168.1.1 >>/var/log/netdebug
# Show that DNS can translate "google.com" to an IP addres
# and that the Internet is reachable.
echo "\n# ping -c 3 google.com" >>/var/log/netdebug
ping -c 3 google.com >>/var/log/netdebug
```

Answer (score 2):

Very probably, the PI was allocated a different IP address upon reboot. Since you are using DHCP the address can change. Assuming the default name of your PI is `raspberrypi` and you have Mdns aka Zeroconf aka Bonjour running on your Windows machine, you may be able to use a local hostname instead of an IP address.

In case you have Itunes installed on your computer, I think it comes with Bonjour.

Try: `ping raspberrypi.local`.

Otherwise, if you turn on network discovery or use a port scanner, you should be able to locate the PI and determine its current IP address.

Comment: I am using advanced IP scanner(https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) and the static ip of pi remains the same after boot.

Comment: Can you ping the PI ? When you try to SSH into it what kind of error message do you get ?

Comment: No,i try to ping both raspberrypi.mshome.net and ip adress that ip scanner gives me and i get "Request timeout".In Putty i get "Network error:Connection timeout".

Comment: Is it possible for you to connect a keyboard and a screen to the PI to check a few things without SSH ? For example `systemctl status sshd.service` to verify that SSH is really running. Also check IP address on the PI direct + current routing rules.

Comment: yes,this is my next move.Thank you very much fo your responses and time!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues using an iPhone as the wifi broadcaster. Sometimes I could connect through ssh, sometimes I couldn't although I could still ping the device (raspberry pi zero w).

Turning ON "Maximize Compatibility" allowed me to ssh reliably from my laptop.